# How to retrieve only a selected portion of online resource

Tags: c#, python, web-scraping

Is it possible to retrieve only a selected portion of specified URL in C#/python or any other, to reduce network traffic.

For Example:
I want to scrape a website and have lets say a thousand urls to process but I only need a small portion of the web page (skip to 100 and download next 200 bytes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading portions *that* small is actually going to increase network traffic (and server load, too). For your use case, if you really only want that one range from each resource, you might want to request `Range: bytes=0-1024`, and use a streaming API to stop reading (and close the socket) at 1024 bytes even if you get the whole file, and manually pick out bytes `[100:300]` of what you get back.

But there are cases where this is definitely worth doing. Let's say you were trying to read, say, the 2nd and 54th megabytes of a 200MB file; you don't want to read the whole 200MB just to keep 1% of it, right?

The simple version is this: you send a [`Range`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) header in your request. You may get back:

- A [206](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.7) response with a [`Content-Range`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.16) header, with just the bytes you wanted in the body.
- A [416](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.17) saying that your range can't be satisfied, using with a `Content-Range` that suggests what you should have been asking for.
- Any other success response, with the whole resource in the body. (You may want to use a "streaming" API instead of a "fetch everything at once" API to deal with this case, so you can at least stop reading after 54MB.)
- Any other error, obviously.

If you want to find out in advance if your request is likely to be satisfied with a 406, you should do a `HEAD` request to get the [`Content-Length`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.13) and [`Accept-Ranges`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.5) headers. But notice that neither of these is actually required.

Also, note that some servers handle simple range requests, but not the full spec of everything required. So, while it may seem like fetching both ranges in a single request would have a bit of overhead over making two requests, it may also increase the chances of falling back to the whole file, so it may not be worth doing.

Anyway, I don't know of any library that makes it all completely trivial, but any mid-level HTTP library (including the ones built into both the Python stdlib and .NET) should make this relatively easy. I'm going to show an example using the third-party [`requests`](http://python-requests.org) library in Python interactively:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://example.com'
>>> h = requests.head(url)
>>> h.headers['Accept-Ranges']
'bytes'
>>> h.headers['Content-Length']
'1270'
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers={'Range': 'bytes=500-600'})
>>> r.status_code
206
>>> r.headers['Content-Range']
500-600/1270
>>> len(r.text)
101
>>> r.text
' 5em auto;\n        padding: 50px;\n        background-color: #fff;\n        border-radius: 1em;\n    }\n '
```

Notice that HTTP ranges are closed—that is, `Bytes: 500-600` includes both 500 and 600, so it's 101 long, while a Python `range(500, 600)` would only be 100 long. Off by one errors are easy to make here.